VS Code Chromium / Firefox debugger "Unable to attach browser"
Working in VS Code on a Vite project, I seem unable to launch nor attach debugger neither with Chromium nor Firefox.
What is happening
Launching Chromium
Error

Unable to launch browser: "Unable to attach to browser"

Configuration
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:5173/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },

Attaching Chromium
Error

Cannot connect to the target at localhost:0: Could not connect to debug target at http://localhost:0: Could not find any debuggable target

Configuration
    {
      "name": "Attach Chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:5173/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },

Launching Firefox
Error
Silent Error
Configuration
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "launch",
      "reAttach": true,
      "name": "Launch Firefox",
      "url": "http://localhost:5173/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "tmpDir": "${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/.vite"
    },

Attaching Firefox
Error

connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:6000

Configuration
    {
      "type": "firefox",
      "request": "attach",
      "name": "Attach Firefox",
      "url": "http://localhost:5173/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },

Software Versions

Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
VS Code 1.91.1 (snap)
Firefox 128.0.3 (snap)
Chromium 126.0.6478.182 (snap)

Additionnal infos

I can use VS Code debugger with node.js processes
I cannot use VS Code debugger with Firefox / Chromium in my other projects where it worked before
I made an install of Docker + Docker Compose (through Lando) last week and I have a dockerd process constantly running (starts again instantly after being killed).

If somebody has an idea about how I could investigate on this issue, I'll be very glad.
Thanks.

I have found several workarounds for the four configurations written in my question. Overall, it seems that I have to be explicit about the ports used by the debugger.
Chromium
Attach
This answer on a similar question pretty much sums it up.
I had to launch chromium with option: chromium --remote-debugging-port=9222 and the launch.json configuration looks like:
    {
      "name": "Attach Chrome",
      "request": "attach",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:5173/*",
      "port": 9222,
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },

Launching
For launching Chromium, I had to setup the "runtimeExecutable" and the "runtimeArgs", I have only been able to make it work with a custom "--user-data-dir" path.
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "runtimeExecutable": "/snap/bin/chromium",
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--remote-debugging-port=9222",
        "--user-data-dir=${workspaceFolder}/.vscode/chromium"
      ],
      "port": 9222,
      "url": "http://localhost:5173/*",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    },

Firefox
Before configuring VS Code, I had to configure Firefox . Either going into the about:config and setting the configuration options like written in the Firefox debugger documentation: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug
Or downloading the Developer Edition, then use the VS Code extension settings to set the path to the exectuable "firefox.executable": "/opt/firefox/firefox".
In both cases, I also configured the port in VS Code extension settings: "firefox.port": 6000
Attach
Firefox needs to be started with the -start-debugger-server 6000 option, but I didn't manage to have the option working with the Developer Edition somehow (could be my install).
Launch
I added the option in the VS Code extensions settings as well: "firefox.args": ["-start-debugger-server 6000"]

I am still not able to make breakpoints work in Firefox, although they do in Chromium. I might have to configure some path mappings but VS Code isn't proposing some like it used to do, so I will have to fiddle with it a little... unless someone has a solution...
